# What does each vehicle indicator bar mean?

Tags: unturned

When looking at a vehicle, it shows 4 status bars, but I cannot deduce what any of them mean:

[image: Status bars when you are inside the vechicle]

Can someone please explain what they all stand for?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot? From what I remember, vanilla Unturned only shows 3 bars when you look at a vehicle, and they were gas, vehicle health, and battery energy.

Comment: @LeoS. There are really just 3 status bars when you look the vehicle from outside. Comparing now, I see the only one that is added when you are inside the vehicle is the Speedometer. So I believe everything is explained now. Would you like to provide an answer to the question?

Comment: Didn't Unturned come with a tutorial where these things are pointed out?

Comment: @Joachim Where is this tutorial?

Comment: You can get there through the main menu, I think. I have a "Graduation. Complete your education" achievement because of it. EDIT: It's a map, see [here](https://unturned.fandom.com/wiki/Tutorial).

Comment: @Joachim Oh, I completely forgot about the Tutorial level. It's been ages since I last played Unturned. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your screenshot, from top to bottom:

1. Fuel meter
2. Speedometer
3. Vehicle Health
4. Battery Life

Source: [watched this video](https://youtu.be/s1_WIWsIf54?t=262) to which they point out the lighting bolt icon is the battery, and also which one is the fuel gauge, and information from the [Wiki](https://unturned.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Vehicle). The rest is pretty self-explanatory.

The battery can be drained by the headlights, but it charges up while operating the vehicle.  So be sure to turn them off when you don't need them/leave the vehicle.